# getstring and locale not always working

Tags: java, android

I have an application with two languages so i have to values folders (values and values-ar)

all the string values from values folder are displaying normally when calling them in getstring or in the xml; but when I call a string from values-ar (after setting locale) sometimes it's giving me string from values and sometimes a string from values-ar (I tried in the same code **getString(R.string.load_more)** and **getString(R.string.all)**)
I checked if I have duplicate fields in values-ar that might not be translated but that's not the case.

I've already set the locale like this:

```
Locale locale ;
Configuration config = new Configuration();
locale= new Locale("ar");
Locale.setDefault(locale); 
config.locale = locale;   
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

What could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Usually, this is caused by a missing translation of a string.

Comment: Try to recompile (twice to be sure) and redeploy. Then try again. Maybe you need to delete the auto-created R-files.

Comment: this wasn't the problem. there was an error in the values-ar/string.xml  <string  translatable="true" name="book_an_appointment">TEXT IN ARABIC/string>. it didn't give an error. had to find it manually. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem

there was an entry in values-ar/strings.xml that was like this

```
<string translatable="true" name="book_an_appointment">TEXT IN ARABIC/string>
```

instead of like this

```
<string translatable="true" name="book_an_appointment">TEXT IN ARABIC</string>
```

it's weird that I didn't get any compilation or runtime errors.

Thank you